# Cannot initialize FFImageLoading, exception thrown

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I am trying to use the FFImageLoading in a cross-platform xamarin app.

I followed the instructions, and installed the Xamarin.FFImageLoading and Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms in both the android and IOS projects.

I then use this code to intitialize the library:

```
[Activity (Label = "app", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme="@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar; 

        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        CachedImageRenderer.Init();

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.XamarinAndroid.AuthenticationConfiguration.Init(this, bundle);

        LoadApplication (new TheWillowEffect.App ());


    }
}
```

I haven't tried in it IOS yet. Not a priority.

I have the following XAML just to see if it works:

```
<ContentPage
....xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"....>

....

    <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
        WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
        DownsampleToViewSize="true"
        Source = "http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1">
```

When I run it, I get:

```
System.MissingMethodException: method 'FFImageLoading.Forms.Droid.CachedImageRenderer.init()' not found.
```

Not sure what's going on. I suspect intellisense would have caught a missing `using`, and there are no errors during compile, only the one above, at runtime.

What have I done wrong!?

Comment: have you tried to clean the solution? are you add the correct "using" in xamarin.Android?

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro wow.... Just had to clean.... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to clean the project and rebuild.